# Least Squares method and Octave/Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, linear-programming, least-squares

I'll try to be as clear as possible so that you understand what I'm trying to do and can help me

I have twelve pairs of data $(x_1,y_1),....,(x_{12},y_{12})$ and from this data we established a model of polynomial regression trough Least Squares,a model like this
$$y=a_0+a_ix+a_2x^2$$

until then I had no problems, but to make the graphs of that model I need more points, and my question is how do I get these points and how do I plot these points with the curve established by my model with the octave / matlab

I have set the coefficients $a_0,a_1,a_2$. The range of points is $x_1=1,x_2=2,..,x_{13}=13$

Comment: Have you already found the values $a_0$, $a_1$ and $a_2$? In which range should $x$ be in your plot?

Comment: Probably you want to have a look on the `linspace` and `polyval` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
% Data
x_data = ...
y_data = ...

% Polynomial fit
p = polyfit(x_data, y_data, 2);

% Plot
N = 42;
x = linspace(x_data(1), x_data(end), N);
y = polyval(p, x);
plot(x,y); legend('Nice plot');
```

Comment: The OP had already handled the `polyfit`-equivalent step in his own code.

Comment: @JosephK And? Also: OP does not know about `polyval`, so it is reasonable to assume that he might not be aware of `polyfit` reducing the fitting to a one-liner.

Comment: Well the question he asked was narrower, just what to do once you have the function calibrated and you want to plot it. Maybe it would be interesting to search for the parameters using simulated annealing, but I wouldn't post it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the additional points that you need.

The fitting algorithm provides you with the values $a_0$, $a_1$ and $a_2$. Let's say that $x_m$ is the minimum value across your $x$-points and that $x_M$ is the maximum value. You can get a chart of your fitted curve by doing something like

`x = linspace(x_m, x_M);
y = a_0 + a_1 * x + a_2 * x .* x;
plot(x, y)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first choose the range, of your plot. Since your data points go from $1$ to $13$, a reasonable range might be the interval $[0,15]$. Then do the following:

```
xs = 0;
xe = 15;
x = xs:0.01:xe;
y = a_0 + a_1 * x + a_2 * x.^2;
plot(x,y)
```